DataCloud web sdk doesnt work for me when I send event
I have added the CDN script in the webpage. Passed consent and sending event on button click but data is not getting reflected in data cloud.
My schema:
{"records":[{"masterLabel":"Custom Form Page","developerName":"customFormPage","category":"Engagement","externalDataTranFields":[{"masterLabel":"category","developerName":"category","dataType":"Text","isDataRequired":true},{"masterLabel":"dateTime","developerName":"dateTime","dataType":"DateTime","isDataRequired":true},{"masterLabel":"deviceId","developerName":"deviceId","dataType":"Text","isDataRequired":true},{"masterLabel":"eventId","developerName":"eventId","dataType":"Text","isDataRequired":true,"primaryIndexOrder":1},{"masterLabel":"eventType","developerName":"eventType","dataType":"Text","isDataRequired":true},{"masterLabel":"sessionId","developerName":"sessionId","dataType":"Text","isDataRequired":true},{"masterLabel":"name","dataType":"Text","developerName":"attributesName","isDataRequired":false},{"masterLabel":"email","dataType":"Text","developerName":"attributesEmail","isDataRequired":false},{"masterLabel":"address","dataType":"Text","developerName":"attributesAddress","isDataRequired":false},{"masterLabel":"phoneNumber","dataType":"Text","developerName":"attributesPhoneNumber","isDataRequired":false}]}]}

And my send event function on button click:
 <script>
  SalesforceInteractions.init({
    consents: [
      {
        provider: "One Trust",
        purpose: "Tracking",
        status: SalesforceInteractions.ConsentStatus.OptIn,
      },
    ],
  }).then(() => {
    console.log("init success");
  });

  function test() {
    //alert("clicked");
    SalesforceInteractions.setLoggingLevel(5);

    SalesforceInteractions.sendEvent({
      interaction: {
        name: "customFormData",
        catalogObject: {
          type: "Form",
          id: "form-1",
          attributes: {
            name: "sumit singh",
          },
        },
      },
    });
  }
</script>


Do you get a debug output from the sendEvent call?
Something like: [DEBUG]: Sent event:
Object { interaction: {…}, source: {…}, user: {…}, consents: [] }
